# Custom buttons for Print and Save in jQuery DataTable Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

I want to use my custom buttons for the save and print data table and these buttons are available outside the data table. Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: you have to be precise. if you want to have pertinent answers, try to add pieces of  your script

Comment: Thanks @AbdallahArffak, I have done this.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide your default jQuery data-table PRINT button by adding the following code in script.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.dt-buttons').attr('hidden',true);
});
```

Then add a custom button where ever you want with an `onclick` event like,

```
<button onclick="printtabledetails()" type="button">My Print Button</button>
```

Then call default print button's click event from `printtabledetails()` function.

```
      function printtabledetails(){
        $(".buttons-print")[0].click();
      }
```